# Why wrap neovim config in a table?

Tags: neovim

I've noticed that some neovim configs are separated into several files or folders and the content of each file is wrapped in code like so:

```
local M = {}

function M.name()
   ~~~~~~~~
   ~~~~~~~~
   bunch of code
end

return M
```

I never do this and I'm curious if there's any advantage to this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the content of each file is wrapped in code like so

This is a typical pattern in Lua used to keep a bunch of references alive without polluting global scope too much. In Lua all entities (including code chunks) are "refcount'd". If no reference left then the stuff goes straight into the garbage collector.

> if there's any advantage to this approach?

This is not about "advantageous approach". Some people do, because they need; and others, because they know how to copy/paste.